# How to get my c-lightning node's private key?

Tags: private-key, core-lightning

`lightning-cli getinfo` outputs my node's id, which is its public key. How can I get its underlying private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c-lightning uses [this code](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/bad0ac6ed615107e129458f0d40915847bdddd08/hsmd/hsmd.c#L300-L304) to obtain the node's private key from the `hsm_secret`.

I've came up with a way to do the same using Python and posted my highly-commented tutorial-like code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/fiatjaf/e3232bef6d59263b439b97b6d04d1bcc).

Basically you have to call an [`hkdf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKDF) function with the `hsm_secret` contents, a salt which will usually be zero, `\x00`, and the label `"nodeid"`.